# Debugging Ember-cli-mirage when routes are not being called

Tags: ember-cli, json-api, ember-cli-mirage

I have successfully created one route in ember-cli-mirage, but am having trouble loading the related data.

The API should be returning JSON API compliant data.

I'm not really sure if there are any good methods or not for debugging mirage's request interception. Here is my config.js

```
export default function() {
    this.urlPrefix = 'https://myserver/';
    this.namespace = 'api/v1';

    this.get('/machines', function(db, request) {
        return {
            data: db.machines.map(attrs => (
              {
                  type: 'machines', 
                  id: attrs.id, 
                  attributes: attrs 
              }
            ))
        };
    });

    this.get('/machines/:id', function(db, request){
        let id = request.params.id;
        debugger;

        return {

            data: {
                type: 'machines',
                id: id,
                attributes: db.machines.find(id),
                relationships:{
                    "service-orders": db["service-orders"].where({machineId: id})
                }
            }
        };
    });

    this.get('/machines/:machine_id/service-orders', function(db, request){
        debugger; // this never gets caught
    });
}
```

Most of this is working fine (I think). I can create machines and service orders in the factory and see the db object being updated. However, where my application would normally make a call to the api for service-orders: //myserver/machines/:machine_id/service-orders, the request is not caught and nothing goes out to the API

**EDIT:**
This is the route that my Ember app is using for /machines/:machine_id/service-orders:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(MachineFunctionalRouteMixin, {
  model: function() {
    var machine = this.modelFor('machines.show');
    var serviceOrders = machine.get('serviceOrders');
    return serviceOrders;
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

And the model for machines/show:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var machine = this.store.find('machine', params.machine_id);
    return machine;
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    var machinesController = this.controllerFor('machines');
    machinesController.set('attrs.currentMachine', model);
  }
});
```

Intuitively, I would think that `machine.get('serviceOrders');` would make a call to the API that would be intercepted and handled by Mirage. Which does not seem to be the case

Comment: first I'd try commenting that last route out. If you do, does mirage complain that you don't have a route defined to handle that request?

Comment: No it doesn't. It did prior to installing Mirage. I've add my route/model that should make a call to the API

Comment: disable mirage completely and make sure your ember app is actually attempting the request http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/server-configuration/#enabled

Comment: when mirage is disabled, a request is sent to `//myserver/machines/:machine_id/service-orders`